# Copying Formatting in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am facing an issue with a small piece of VBA I have been using.

I have values in Column A, I want only values in bold to remain into Column A.

The Code I am using is:

```
Sub CopyBoldText()
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrBelow = 0
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Intersect(Columns("B"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
If c.Font.Bold Then c.Offset(, -1).Value = c.Value
Next c
End Sub
```

My issue is that the values in Column A are numbers with proceeding zero's when the values are copied and inserted in Column A these leading values are dropped.

I have tried varying the CopyOrigin switch between the following :

```
xlFormatFromLeftOrBelow = 0
xlFormatFromLeftOrBelow = 1
xlFormatFromRightOrBelow = 0
xlFormatFromRightOrBelow = 1
```

But each time the values still appear without the leading Zeroes.

Comment: Well how have you kept the leading zeros in column A? I imagine you've done something like formatting them as text? In that case, do something similar for the new column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the line

```
Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "@"
```

after the `Selection.Insert`.  This will make the format of the whole column text which is the only way that you will not lose the leading zeroes on numbers.

Comment: Hello, Thank you, this worked great, the code is now working

Answer (score 0):

If this is a formatting issue, why not copy the format with `PasteSpecial` for the whole column.

```
Columns("B").Copy
Columns("A").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub CopyBoldText()
    Columns("A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrAbove
    Columns("B").Copy
    Columns("A").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Intersect(Columns("B"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        If c.Font.Bold Then c.Offset(, -1).Value = c.Value
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I was still facing the same issue, using the Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "@" as suggested below corrected the issue